# Как программно вызвать контекстное меню?

Tags: java, android-sdk, android

Как вызвать контекстное меню через Java код, прямиком из Actyivity? У меня есть метод:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, dictionaries[Resources.dictionaryToDelete_ID]);
}
```

Какие аргументы нужно передать для вызова?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [гуглу](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20manually%20call%20context%20menu), [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2926081/3212712) и [документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29), в активити пишем:

1. Находим `View`, коему хотим вызвать контекстное меню:

   > View v = findViewById(R.id.YOURS_VIEW_ID);
2. Приказываем ему реагировать на вызов контекстного меню:

   > registerForContextMenu(v).
3. Заставляем его среагировать:

   > openContextMenu(v);

Comment: Юрий, чтобы я без Вас делал! :) Столько раз меня выручали и, думаю, выручите! :D К сожалению, с английским у меня не очень...

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста) А ангийский придёт сам собой вместе со скилом в кодописании)

Comment: Ох... Сколько же мне еще писать и писать! :D Да и многое, скорее всего, перехватить в школе сумею, время еще есть (я в 9 классе, мне 14 :)).

Comment: Тем более) У меня начальные знания из англ. версии 2-ой дьяблы вообще)

Comment: Как я Вас понимаю :)).